# two x axis and one data series in highchart highstock charts and on tool tip both x axis should show for the data series

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

working on high charts. Need to update dual x axis, but only one data sereies has to scale and on tool tip has to show dual x axis values with legends.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kPqKW/

Comment: in case when you need to update any axis, you can use http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.update